# Заставка при запуске GWT приложения

Tags: gwt, java

Можно ли во время загрузки приложения отображать свою заставку, картинку например?

Comment: На самом деле это в development действительно долго. Скомпилированный грузится быстро. Картинка только мелькать будет.

Comment: Это не обязательно. Иногда для приложения требуется загрузить с сервера какие-то данные или проинициализировать сессию. Тогда это требуется, а не только в случае медленной загрузки ресурсов и инициализации скрипта.

Comment: Обычно это уже после того, как onModuleLoad() отработал, при первом обращении к базе и т.п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно.

Для этого надо сверстать статическую часть страницы так, чтобы там была картинка или что-то типа `Loading...` а потом скриптом, когда сработает `onModuleLoad`, всё это убрать и включить нужные `div`'ыпанели.